# How to submit a "vector of distributions" to a function in R?

Tags: r

I want to write an R-function, say `f`, which has inputs `x` and `n`, where `x` is some kind of "list of distributions" and `f` is supposed to draw `n` samples from each distribution in `x`.

What is a good way to implement this in R?

My current idea is

```r
f = function(x,n){
  
  out = list()
  
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    
    name = sub("\\(.*", "",x[i])
    size = ifelse(name=="sample",paste("size=",n),paste0("n=",n))
    args = paste(size,gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(x[i], gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", x[i]))[[1]]),sep=",")
    out[[i]] = eval(parse(text=paste0(name,"(",args,")")))
    
  }
  
  return(out)
  
}

f(x = c("rnorm(mean=1,sd=2)","sample(0:1,replace=TRUE)","rbinom(size=10,prob=0.1)"), n = 10)
```

I don't like this implementation, because

1. `n` is not always the input name for the sample size (e.g. in `sample` it is `size`),
2. the code will crash if not all inputs for the distributions are properly defined.

Can I improve the implementation, for example with `x` of class alist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change your input and create a list of function names and arguments. For each distribution we set the `n`/`size`-value to `1`.

```r
ls_func <- list("rnorm" = list(mean = 0, sd = 1, n = 1),
                "sample" = list(x = 0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 1),
                "rbinom" = list(size = 10, prob = 0.1, n = 1))
```

Your function takes those distributions and replicates them `n`-times:

```r
g <- function(ls_func, n) {
  out = list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(ls_func)){
    out[[i]] <- replicate(do.call(names(ls_func)[i], ls_func[[i]]), n = n)
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

so

```r
set.seed(4096)
g(ls_func, 10)
```

returns

```r
[[1]]
 [1]  0.1894398 -0.1622468  0.5327100 -1.5747229 -0.6884024 -0.3092226 -0.0879258 -0.4320240 -0.7799596  0.4525895

[[2]]
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

or. Basically it's not a good approach to use `eval(parse(text=...))` to execute functions. Use `do.call` instead.

---

You can remove the `for`-loop:

```r
g <- function(ls_func, n) {
  out = list()
 
  out <- lapply(seq_along(ls_func), function(i) replicate(do.call(names(ls_func)[i], ls_func[[i]]), n = n))
  
  return(out)
}
```

**Note:** This code also crashes, if your distributions aren't defined properly. To avoid this, you need some error handling. Look for `try` and `stop` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been putting together an R package -- [distionary](https://distionary.netlify.app) -- that can help with this.

First make a list of input distributions:

```
library(distionary)
x <- list(
  dst_norm(1, 2^2),
  dst_empirical(0:1),
  dst_binom(10, 0.1)
)
```

The function for drawing from a distribution is `realize()`, which fits nicely  with `lapply()` (or purrr's `map()`):

```
set.seed(123)
lapply(x, realize, n = 10)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] -0.1209513  0.5396450  4.1174166  1.1410168  1.2585755  4.4301300
#>  [7]  1.9218324 -1.5301225 -0.3737057  0.1086761
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 3 2 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 0
```

Putting this code in a function is then straightforward:

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  lapply(x, realize, n = n)
}
set.seed(123)
f(x, n = 10)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] -0.1209513  0.5396450  4.1174166  1.1410168  1.2585755  4.4301300
#>  [7]  1.9218324 -1.5301225 -0.3737057  0.1086761
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 3 2 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 0
```